# the Events, js beforeunload does not work with mozilla

Tags: javascript, web, exit

In JavaScript Events, `beforeunload` event does not fire on `mozilla`, but it works fine in `chrome`. How can I know that the user has left my site, **is there such event that would work cross browser?**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function(){ 
     window.onbeforeunload=function(){
                          $.post("msds.php",{likof:5});
                        }; 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please check your code, because mozilla support this event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: @muneebShabbir OK  I have published my code

Comment: please place alert to make sure the event triggered or not

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, this might help you

```
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable

            myEvent(chkevent, function(e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
                alert("code executed")
                $.post("msds.php",{likof:5});
            });
```